# flash loading external swf and change child input text field value

Tags: flash

Running into a wall here. I'm working with Flash AS2 and I have the following problem hope you can help.

I have a holder swf and a form swf. The holder loads the form swf
_level0.myMC1.createEmptyMovieClip ("vaCell", _level0.myMC1.getNextHighestDepth ());
_level0.myMC1.loadMovie('form.swf');

The form contains input fields, dynamic text. with instance name ie 'title'

How can i change the text of the form.swf from with in the holder.swf
_level0.myMC1.title.text= 'hello world'; does nothing

Help is much ablidged.

Regards,

Arnaud

Comment: I just made more progress. as i understand when you use loadmovie the mc will no longer be an mc object. After more searching i found that you need a loader:
// set up loader, an instance of MovieClipLoader, and use the main timeline ("this")
// to listen to and respond to its broadcast events
var loader:MovieClipLoader = new MovieClipLoader();
loader.addListener(this);

// define what should happen when the jpg/swf is completely loaded
function onLoadInit(_mc:MovieClip) {
   // code here
   _mc.title.htmlText= '<h1>1test</h1>';
   trace(_mc.title.htmlText);
};

Comment: but it still doesnt show

Answer (score 0):

So the solution works. I noticed that there were version differences with the parent and child. Both are 9 now and it work!.

Regards,

Arnaud